# Ubuntu Kernel Panic on installation (quanta s215-x12ks)

Tags: server, system-installation, kernel

I have a server quanta s215-x12ks.

[image: main logo]

[image: bios]

I'm trying to install ubuntu/debian there, but I always get "kernel panic" when the installation starts...

[image: kernel panic description]

If someone has such servers, tell me what could be the problem?

I tried to install debian 8,9,10 and Ubuntu Server 18.04.4, 20.04.2, used builds "amd64 live-server/netinst"

Comment: The system date is several years out of date in your BIOS. This could be leading to some validation issues. Update your BIOS and give it a try (with Ubuntu), then report back if the issue continues.

Comment: Thank you for fixing... i got answer from support today:

Hi,
It seems that this happened due to S215-X12KS does not support more advanced kernels.
Since this model is “End of life” from the beginning of 2016, we can’t offer any hardware/software support to fix this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

debian-8.10.0-amd64-netinst.iso - OK

[Need small configure BIOS settings...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPXWE.jpg)